# Is there a pattern of the length between one even Fibonacci number and another?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers, pattern-recognition

I had seen a math problem  asking for the sum of all even Fibonacci numbers up to 4 million, but I still need to know this: Is there an obvious pattern of the distance between a even Fibonacci number and the next?

Comment: You mean, as in the fact that $F_n\text{ is even }\iff n\text{ is divisible by }3$?

Comment: Have you tried the first few numbers of the sequence to see what happens?

Comment: @Jack and @ QianLi, for clarification, are you wanting the "sum of every other fibonacci number" i.e. the fibonacci numbers with even index, or "the sum of the fibonacci numbers that are even."  In still other words, do you consider $F_4=3$ to be included in the sum (because it is the **fourth** fibonacci number and *four* is even) or not be included in the sum (because the number is **three** and *three* is not even)?

Comment: @JMoravitz I don't want F4 to be included because the **RESULT** isn't even.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may notice for first that $F_n\equiv 0\pmod{2}\Longleftrightarrow n\equiv 0\pmod{3}$, then:
$$ 2\sum_{k=1}^{K}F_{3k} = \sum_{k=1}^{K}\left(F_{3k-2}+F_{3k-1}+F_{3k}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{3K}F_n = F_{3K+2}-1 \tag{1}$$
and:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{K}F_{3k}=\frac{F_{3K+2}-1}{2}.\tag{2} $$
Since the last Fibonacci number less than four millions is $F_{33}=3524578$, the answer (i.e. the sum of every non-negative and even Fibonacci number less than $4\cdot 10^6$) is given by:
$$\frac{F_{35}-1}{2}=\color{red}{4613732}.\tag{3}$$